# How to write the analytical equation for the SARIMA model?

Tags: arima, seasonality

If the coefficients for the SARIMA(p, 0, q)(P, 0, Q)[12] model are estimated to be:

[image]

How do I write the analytical equation of the model? Should it be $X_t = -0.6856 \phi Z_t +0.3983 \phi Z_{t-1} + 0.768 \Theta X_{t-12}$?